# Win 8.1 Bootloader: Your PC Needs to be repaired/A device required for boot is not connected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Hello Fellow Ubuntuans!

I've got *Ubuntu 14.04* and *Windows 8.1 pro* dual booting on my PC and everything has been fine until about a month ago. Recently every time I reboot into Windows *after Ubuntu* I get a boot failure saying `your PC needs to be repaired` and that `a device required to boot isn't connected`. I reboot and it's fine. I reboot another few times and as long as I don't pick Ubuntu in the bootloader screen it boots fine. Once I boot into Ubuntu, my first Windows boot after that fails.

Now obviously the error is bogus (since a mere reboot fixes it without me reconnecting this magical invisible device that is so important to booting), but I'm wondering if maybe Ubuntu or Microsoft caused this with an update.

Things were definitely fine with *Ubuntu 13.10*, but now I'm on *14.04*. The problem is I don't often switch back & forth on this machine so I don't know if maybe 14.04 is the culprit (it defaults to Windows as it's my gaming machine. I boot Linux if I'm coding).

Is anyone else experiencing this? Does anyone have any ideas?

All I've come across in terms of suggestions have been the various *fixes* for the boot loop issue, but there's no loop here: once and it's done!

Thanks

Comment: Never experiencied that, and I have the exact same dual boot. When you close Ubuntu, you leave somehow the Windows partition mounted ?

Comment: I rarely ever mount the Windows partitions in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I noticed that it wasn't happening only when I booted from Ubuntu into Windows, but also when I started the computer after having it off.

I disabled the `fast startup` feature and this fixed the issue both on my laptop and my PC.

[image: Disabling fast startup]